How to handle the accessibility of a filter and result buttons for a list of checkboxes?
Let's say I'm trying to build a multi-select input using a list of checkboxes:

I've put the checkboxes inside a <fieldset> with a <legend> label
There is an input that lets the user filter the checkboxes to make it easy to select ones they want to
When a checkbox is selected (checked), a result button to shown to the user. Clicking on this button also unchecks the checkbox (unselects) it. Again, this is mainly for UX, because it's helpful for the users to see the items they have already selected.
The filter and the checkboxes are placed inside <details> and <summary> to give it the traditional select box look.

Here's the working demo:


("use strict");

// Focus on the filter input when the options are expanded/opened
document.querySelectorAll(".options-details").forEach(function (details) {
    details.addEventListener("toggle", function () {
        if (details.hasAttribute("open")) {
            details.querySelector(".filter-input").focus();
        }
    });
});

// Filter options
document.querySelectorAll(".filter-input").forEach(function (input) {
    input.addEventListener("input", function () {
        const options = input.closest("fieldset").querySelectorAll(".btn-check");
        options.forEach(function (option) {
            option.classList.remove("d-none");
            const value = option.value.toLowerCase();
            if (value !== "" && !value.includes(input.value.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                option.classList.add("d-none");
            }
        });
    });
});

// Add option button when an option is checked
document.querySelectorAll(".btn-check").forEach(function (input) {
    input.addEventListener("input", function () {
        if (input.checked === true) {
            const optionButtonItem = document.createElement("li");
            optionButtonItem.innerHTML = `<button class="option-button btn btn-primary" type="button" id="${input.getAttribute("id")}-remove" aria-describedby="option-remove">${input.getAttribute("value")}</button>`;
            input.closest("fieldset").querySelector(".option-buttons-list").appendChild(optionButtonItem);

            // Add event listener to remove option and button and uncheck option
            const optionButton = document.getElementById(`${input.getAttribute("id")}-remove`);
            optionButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
                document.getElementById(optionButton.getAttribute("id").slice(0, -7)).checked = false;
                optionButton.closest("li").remove();
            });
        } else {
            document
                .getElementById(`${input.getAttribute("id")}-remove`)
                .closest("li")
                .remove();
        }
    });
});
:root {
     --bs-font-size-base: 1rem;
     --bs-font-size-sm: 0.875rem;
     --bs-font-size-lg: 1.125rem;
}

.option-button::after {
     content: "\00D7";
     margin-left: 12px;
}

.options-container {
     min-height: 36px;
     max-height: 300px;
}

.btn-check.d-none + .btn-secondary {
     display: none;
}

.btn-check:checked + .btn-secondary {
     background-color: var(--bs-primary) !important;
     color: var(--bs-primary-foreground) !important;
}

.btn-check:focus-visible + .btn-secondary {
     background-color: var(--bs-primary-100) !important;
     box-shadow: none !important;
}

.btn-check:checked:focus-visible + .btn-secondary {
     background-color: var(--bs-primary-active-bg) !important;
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Halfmoon/2.0.1/css/halfmoon.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="min-vh-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="specific-w-600 mw-100 p-5">
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="form-label">Select the languages you want*</legend>
            <p class="text-body-secondary mb-4">
                Let's get started with the survey. First, please choose all
                of the languages that you know.
            </p>
            <span id="option-remove" class="visually-hidden">remove</span>
            <ul
                id="options-selected"
                class="option-buttons-list list-unstyled d-flex flex-wrap gap-1 m-0"
                ></ul>
            <details class="options-details border rounded mt-2 overflow-hidden">
                <summary class="px-3 py-2">
                    Choose one or more options
                </summary>
                <div class="border-top">
                    <div class="p-3 border-bottom">
                        <span id="filter-label" class="visually-hidden">Filter languages</span>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            class="filter-input form-control"
                            placeholder="Filter languages"
                            aria-autocomplete="list"
                            aria-labelledby="filter-label options-selected"
                            />
                    </div>
                    <div
                        class="options-container d-flex flex-column overflow-y-auto"
                        >
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            class="btn-check"
                            id="checkbox-1"
                            value="Python"
                            autocomplete="off"
                            />
                        <label
                            class="btn btn-secondary text-start px-3 py-2 lh-sm border-0 rounded-0"
                            for="checkbox-1"
                            >
                        Python
                        </label>
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            class="btn-check"
                            id="checkbox-2"
                            value="JavaScript"
                            autocomplete="off"
                            />
                        <label
                            class="btn btn-secondary text-start px-3 py-2 lh-sm border-0 rounded-0"
                            for="checkbox-2"
                            >
                        JavaScript
                        </label>
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            class="btn-check"
                            id="checkbox-3"
                            value="C++"
                            autocomplete="off"
                            />
                        <label
                            class="btn btn-secondary text-start px-3 py-2 lh-sm border-0 rounded-0"
                            for="checkbox-3"
                            >
                        C++
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </details>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</body>



The JavaScript does the following:

When the options are opened, the filter input is focused automatically.
Typing inside the filter input, the checkboxes are filtered using its value.
When a checkbox is selected, a result button is added. And of course, clicking on this button would unselect the checkbox.

My question is this: how accessible is my current setup? In terms of using the correct WAI-ARIA tags on the filter input, result buttons, etc. Moreover, is it okay to use the <details> and <summary> tags here to do what I'm trying to do?

Somehow the halfmoon library is causing the details element to not being selected when using the Tab key (and then Enter key for opening the details element). That is not very user friendly.

This question seems better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com, which is for asking for improvements to working code.

I’m currently checking the ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG) for similar patterns. The question is mixing several patterns, which seem not correctly implemented individually. Keyboard control with arrow keys is unsupported, f.e.

I would say this is a very sophisticated implementation already.
But who is to say if it’s OK to use the <details> element? Standards-wise, it’s ok. Best would be to test it now with users of assistive technology.
I noticed this paragraph from aria-autocomplete:

If an element has aria-autocomplete set to list […], authors MUST ensure both of the following conditions are met:

The element has a value specified for aria-controls that refers to the element that contains the collection of suggested values.
The element has a value for aria-haspopup that matches the role of the element that contains the collection of suggested values.


And then, from aria-haspopup:

[…] Authors MUST ensure that the role of the element that serves as the container for the popup content is menu, listbox, tree, grid, or dialog […]

In turn, a listbox can only have option as accessibility children, not checkbox.
So you’ll need to rework the list. Please refer to my answer to your second question for more details on an accessible list of options (keyboard accessibility, skip links).
  <input
    aria-controls="language-list"
    aria-haspopup="list"
    />
</div>
<ul id="language-list" role="listbox" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <li role="option" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0">Python</li>
  …

The advantage will be, that screen readers can announce the number of items, helping the user decide whether to filter.

I just tested the example from the question with NVDA, and I’m noticing these details:
The list with the remove buttons is lacking a label, to make it clear what the listed languages are:
<ul … aria-label="Selected languages"></ul>

The × is a visual indicator and would better be hidden from assistive technology. content added via CSS is still content. The button is read as the following:

Python times button remove

<button aria-label="Python. Remove">Python</button>

The selected options added to the name of the search input include “times” as well, but that would be solved for with above suggestion.
Adding the selected options to the name of the input is redundant, as the list of selections is available before and after. The well established combobox pattern doesn’t do that either.
The focus is not visible on the collapsed details-summary element.

Tiny details from the code:
Instead of using document.createElement(), which makes the resulting DOM structure hard to read, you might consider using the <template> Element
autocomplete is not useful on an <input type="checkbox">:

It is available on <input> elements that take a text or numeric value as input […]

